# Registration using Facebook Connect API

Tags: facebook

I need to store the values submitted in registration controls using FaceBook Connect API in my data base. Can any one please let me know the way to fetch, also sharing of some code will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to call a webservice from facebook object

```
          Facebook facebook = new Facebook(appId);
          SessionStore.restore(facebook, context);
          String response = facebook.request("me");
```

And then you will get a JSON object in response and you can parse it as per requirements